# Is the cartesian product of two polytopes again a polytope?

Tags: geometry

Given two polytopes $P_1, P_2$ then define the graph on $P_1 \times P_2$ as follows:

$[(a,b),(x,y)]$ is an edge in $P_1 \times P_2$ iff $a=x$ and $[b,y]$ is an edge in $P_2$ or $b=y$ and $[a,x]$ is an edge in $P_1$.

Is this new structure a polytope?

Comment: How can $(b,y)$ be an edge in $P_2$ when $(a,b)\in P_1$? (I don't know anything about polytopes, so if this is trivial, pleas say so.)

Comment: Possibly my notation is confusing. $a,x \in P_1$ and $b,y \in P_2$. I am using pairings to simultaneously denote edges and elements in the Cartesian product. I shall change notation to make it more clear.

Comment: Without your definition of "polytope" it's difficult to be certain. :) Do you mean "the $1$-skeleton (i.e., vertices and edges) of an intersection of finitely many closed half-spaces (possibly subject to additional conditions)"?

Comment: Yes, of course I should have elaborated. By polytope I mean that an n-polytope is the n-dimensional simplicial complex which is bounded by the (n-1)-faces, which are (n-1)-polytope's. A 0-polytope is a point. So a 1-polytope is a line, and so on.